# Adapter keeps falling out of laptop

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm using a refurbished new dell latitude and the adapter keeps falling out, is there any solution to keeping it in. I've tried strapping tape it does not work.

Comment: Power adapter, or some other adapter or expansion card? Please phrase your question as specific as possible, including part/model numbers.

Answer (score 0):

You could put some velcro on your laptop case, and leave a strap to put over your adapter connector. The velcro usually comes with stronger glue because people don't want it falling off. Some velcro types are able to hold a fire extinguisher.

I'm not sure if I can post links to amazon or anything here, so I won't. But if you search for velcro on amazon you're getting some results that are about one thumb width wich should fit my adapter, so I guess others too.

Comment: You can post amazon links if you wish. Not as a shopping recommendation but as a reference. @randy